# issue using data.replace with single and double quotes

Tags: jquery

I am opening up a txt file in ajax and replacing a few lines of html and then inserting it into a value

All is working fine until I get to some html in the text file that has "(", ")" and ', I get errors of course so I escaped those but it won't find the data match since I'm using escape

Here is the text I'm trying to replace

```
('title', 'MY SITE TITLE')
```

Here is data replace and of course you get an error with the extra () and ''

```
data = data.replace('('title', 'MY SITE TITLE')','('title', 'NEW SITE TITLE')');
```

So I escaped them , the error goes away , but it won't replace cause the data doesn't match

```
data = data.replace('\(\'title', \'MY SITE TITLE\'\)','\(\'title\', \'NEW SITE TITLE\'\)');
```

How would anyone suggest making this work properly ?

Comment: in your code, you' ve added backward slashes for replace parameters' qoutes, too. if you want/have to use single quotes then you can try; `data.replace('(\'title\', \'MY SITE TITLE\')','(\'title\', \'NEW SITE TITLE\')');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use double quotes.

```
data = data.replace("('title', 'MY SITE TITLE')","('title', 'NEW SITE TITLE')")
```

Comment: ya right after i posted , i realized what a dummy i was for not seeing the obvious, thanks for the time

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing your string with double quotes (`"`) is one way of dealing with it. I actually used the regular expression `/\('title', 'MY SITE TITLE'\)/g` as this can be used to replace a pattern  multiple times (by using the `g`-flag). But be aware that you will need to mask the special characters `(` and `)` as `\(` and `\)` to avoid them being interpreted as group delimiters:

```js
data = `This is some random HTML with ('title', 'MY SITE TITLE') somewhere strewn into it.
 It appears twice! The second time here: ('title', 'MY SITE TITLE'). And this is the end.`;
console.log( data.replace(/\('title', 'MY SITE TITLE'\)/g,"('title', 'NEW SITE TITLE')") );

// with the latest version of ECMA 262 you can alternatively use .repaceAll():
console.log( data.replaceAll("('title', 'MY SITE TITLE')","('title', 'NEW SITE TITLE')") );
```

As of now (September 2020) `.replaceAll()` is available in all major browsers, see [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-string-replaceall-has-landed-in-all-major-browsers-9417e2f831d4).

Comment: thanks for the .replaceAll use , i can use that as well